# How to equiry data using sql when facing condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
type cost
 A    10
 A    11
 A    12
 B    10
 B    10
```

I have this small sample table. I want to select data where the cost of the same type is different.So the expected outcome should be:

```
type cost
 A    10
 A    11
 A    12
```

The cost for A is different so I need to select these "A" out.
So what is the "select" sentence?

---

Thanks for the replies. Actually my table is little more complex like this

```
type cost people
 A    10   jack
 A    11   frank
 A    12   lucy
 B    10   amy
 B    10   tom
```

I need to select the data meet one of the requirements below:

1. Same type with different cost
2. Same type with people "amy"

So the outcome should be like :

```
type cost people
 A    10   jack
 A    11   frank
 A    12   lucy
 B    10   amy
 B    10   tom
```

Select all of type A because the cost is different
Select all of type B because the people has "amy"
I have firgure out how to select for amy like this:

```
select type, cost, people
from table 
where type in
(select type from table where people = 'amy')
```

I don't know how to combine these conditions.
[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb9d45)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXISTS` to look for another row with same type but other cost:

```
select t1.type, t1.cost
from tablename t1
where exists (select * from tablename t2
              where t2.type = t1.type
                and t2.cost <> t1.cost)
```

Or have a sub-query that returns type values having different costs, and join with that result:

```
select t1.type, t1.cost
from tablename t1
join (select type
      from tablename
      group by type
      having max(cost) <> min(cost)) t2
    on t1.type = t2.type
```

Comment: Hi jarlh, thank you the reply. Could you help me with my further question?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
select 
   t.type, t.cost
from t 
left join t t1 on t.type = t1.type 
   and (t.cost <> t1.cost or t1.people = 'amy')
where 
   not t1.cost is null
group by 
   t.type, t.cost;
```

[`[SQL Fiddle Demo]`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/423d27/7)

Or also:

```
select *
from t
where exists (
  select 1
  from t t1
  where t1.type = t.type
  group by t1.type
  having count(distinct t1.cost) > 1
  -- below code added your new criteria
  union all
  select 1
  from t t2
  where t2.people = 'amy'
);
```

[`[SQL Fiddle Demo]`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/423d27/9)

Comment: Hi,thanks for the reply. Can you help me with the further question?

Comment: Thank you. The first way is unvalid.Could you please post the answer in the SQL FIddle?

Comment: SQL Fiddle attached ;).